# Why Op Amp circuit not behaving as desired

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, pwm

I want to convert PWM output of microcontroller  to 4-20mA. I use below circuit for this 
work :

[image]

But voltage on pin + and - Are not equal in this circuit!!! for example when pin + is 1.2 volt with voltmeter ,pin - is 2.04 volt . while They should be equal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier

in your opinion , what is my problem ?

Comment: In my opinion the problem is an underspecified schematics (values for components missing, unknown voltages etc.), unclear information of measurement procedures and comparison to expected outcome, and unkown possible deviations to what is really on your breadboard.

Comment: @PlasmaHH -Excuse me ,R load is 100 ohm , now enter other value in circuit

Comment: You have a RC filter with a corner frequency of 7.23MHz, and 125kHz PWM. The filter is not doing anything.

Comment: @ Matt Young -ok ,but do Inappropriate selection for RC filter Will be cause This issue?

Comment: It's certainly a factor. This circuit has more problems than you can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "What's my problem?" cannot accurately be answered, since there are at least 5 problems.

1) The problem you're worried about, op amp conditions, has been addressed by Spehro. You are using an inappropriate op amp. Either change the op amp or provide a -12 volt negative supply.

2) An op amp problem not addressed by Spehro is that a 741 is not rated to produce 20 mA of current. It may work in your circuit, or it may not. One sample may work while another may not. The LM358 is better, but its maximum current rating is 20 mA only at 25 C. Over full temperature range it is only rated for 10 mA. As with the 741, it may work or it may not.

3) Although you have produced a current loop transmitter, it is not a 4-20 mA device. As configured, 5 volts on the input will produce 20 mA through your 100 ohm load resistor. 0 volts in will produce 0 mA out.

4) Another consideration is frequency response. Neither a 741 nor an LM358 will work at 125 kHz.

5) Related to 4), sending raw PWM over a 4-20 mA link is just silly. Assuming that you have a uC producing PWM at 0-5 volts, and you want to transmit that to a remotely located driver, you should use a (preferably differential) logic driver. A current loop is the worst possible choice. Current drivers, by their nature, are very high impedance: a perfect current source has infinite impedance. As a result, any capacitance on the line will produce a severe low-pass filter at the receiver, and your PWM signal will be grossly degraded. If you are using a current loop because you have heard that it rejects noise, you should drive a logic-level signal over shielded twisted pair with a controlled receiver impedance to match the link impedance, and optically isolate the receiver.

Comment: THANKS WhatRoughBeast, 1-so i should change 741 op amp ,2-so i can not use of op amp ? because current is problem? ,3-this subject is not problem for me,because i send 1 to 5 volt by program into uC  ,4-so i should change Frequence ,5-i want to send 4-20 mA as AO to AI other device for example PLC ,,,,,,,finally , what is best circuit for this work ??

Comment: I'm still not sure of exactly what you want. If you MUST communicate via current loop, send the PWM modulation signal instead, and generate the PWM itself at the second device. And I don't see how you think you can easily generate a 1-5 volt PWM signal in the first place.

Comment: i only want to generate 4-20 mA for analoge output . for this , What do you suggest ?

Comment: You generate 4-20 mA for analog output. You send this to the second unit. This unit converts the analog signal to PWM, WHICH IS DIGITAL.

Comment: no , second unit is plc(that analog input) and receive 4-20 mA   ,

Comment: OK. So why are you sending PWM? Why not just send the modulating signal?

Comment: because i want to connect to analog module of plc and that only receive 4-20mA.

Comment: Not the question. Please answer - WHY ARE YOU SENDING PWM? The "M" stands for "modulation" and it is the modulation (at some frequency lower than the 125 kHz) which carries the signal of interest. So why not send that instead?

Comment: you ask "WHY ARE YOU SENDING PWM?" my answer:because avr have two way for analog output: 1-PWM , 2-DAC ,in my opinion pwm is better for this task ..
you ask "So why not send that instead?" my answer: do you use of plc? plc have analog module and i want to send to it and it only receive 4-20mA ,no modulation frequence. if your opinion is that i use of DI of plc , i want not to doing this work..tell me if i am in wrong

Comment: You are wrong. Use the DAC.

Answer (score 1):

No opinion involved- the 741 was not a 'single supply' op-amp, so the input common-mode range does not extend to the negative supply rail nor can the output swing all the way to that rail.

Replace it with half an LM358 and much will improve, though that is not really a good way to do 4-20mA- it's preferable to have one side of the load grounded.

Edit: You did not disclose the PWM freqency, but the values shown 100R and 220pF both seem inappropriately low.

Comment: PWM freqency is 125 khz , but do PWM freqency Will be cause This issue

Comment: The uC drive will not be symmetric with such high loading, and did you calculate the ripple voltage? For example, at 50% duty cycle?

Comment: i use of below site to calculate low pass filter http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/PWMtool.php in your opinion ,what is best value for filter ?

Comment: Maybe 20K and 100nF (about 100,000 times higher \$\tau\$), which would give < 0.25% ripple and response time of some milliseconds.

Comment: yes , these values cause output without ripple ,but output voltage can not reach to 5 volt and become 3 volt , do i am in right?

Comment: If your MCU has 5V I/O then 100% duty cycle should give you 5V at the op-amp. What happens after that is another matter. There may not be enough current source ability as @WhatRoughBeast mentions, or you may run out of compliance voltage because of the load resistance.

Comment: i think that should use of other circuit for this work , in your opinion below circuit can work properly ? http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/13985/4-20mA.jpg

Comment: No, that's a cr*p circuit too, but the idea is better, just the usual horrible execution found in free circuits on the internet.